# TypeScript Conditional Generic Interface as Parameter (Array or Object, based on boolean)

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript-generics

I have a function which should be able to receive two similar types as argument. Depending on if `props.multi` is `true` or `false`.

The problem is that it still allows me to pass `value = []` with `multi = false`. How can I get rid of this?

```
interface PropsSingle<T> {
    value: T,
    multi: false
}

interface PropsMulti<T> {
    value: T[],
    multi: true
}

function foo<T>(props: PropsSingle<T> | PropsMulti<T>) {
    if(props.multi) {
        let arr = props.value // type detection works fine
    } else {
        let obj = props.value // type detection works fine
    }
}

foo({multi: true, value: []}) // works as expected
foo({multi: true, value: {}}) // throws error as expected
foo({multi: false, value: {}}) // works as expected
foo({multi: false, value: []}) // THIS SHOULD THROW AN ERROR
```

I already have tried `foo<T extends object>(...)` and `foo<T extends {[key: string]: any}>(...)`

The only kinda solution / workaround I found is this:

```
interface PropsSingle<T> {
    value: T extends any[] ? never : T,
    multi: false
}
```

But that looks weird to me.

Why can't I restrict the type at `function foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason pretty simple, there is nothing preventing `T` in `PropsSingle` to be `any[]`. And there is no simple way to let typescript know that a generic parameter can't extends a given type, we can only specify what `T` extends.

The solution you have should work, I usually add the constraint on the function and use a string literal type to offer a more sugestive error message when dealing with this kind of scenario:

```
interface PropsSingle<T> {
    value: T,
    multi: false
}

interface PropsMulti<T> {
    value: T[],
    multi: true
}

type ErrorIf<T, U, TError> = T extends U ? TError : {} 

function foo<T>(props: (PropsSingle<T> & ErrorIf<T, any[], "Argument to PropsSingle can't be []")| PropsMulti<T>) {
    if(props.multi) {
        let arr = props.value // type detection works fine
    } else {
        let obj = props.value // type detection works fine
    }
}

foo({multi: true, value: []}) // works as expected
foo({multi: true, value: {}}) // throws error as expected
foo({multi: false, value: {}}) // works as expected
foo({multi: false, value: []}) // Error Type '{ multi: false; value: undefined[]; }' is not assignable to type '"Argument to PropsSingle can't be []"'.
```

Comment: Thank you :) . I thought about something like `foo<T, M extends boolean>(props: M extends true ? PropsSingle<T> : PropsMulti<T>)` or something like this. But I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @BenjaminM I don't think that will work unless you specify M and T explicitly, which you probably want to avoid. I have seen similar questions to this several times on SO, I have not seen a better solution unfortunately